# trying to use EPSG:3857 in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, proj4js

I am trying to make leaflet use EPSG:3857 as an input coordinate system. I use porj4leaflet to achieve this. I have defined my map instance like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
center: [8378860.13, 1481133.311008498],
zoom: 7,
crs: new L.Proj.CRS(
  'EPSG:3857',
  '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs',
    {
      resolutions: [
        8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
      ],
      origin: [0, 0]
    }
  )
});
```

When I try to run this, i get `TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers`. You can see the entire fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/asdpinspdai/fckbpq0a/

Of what I understand from the docs, setting the crs like this should allow me to pass coordinates to leaflet in the EPSG:3857 format. Am I missing something?

Any help here is very, very appriciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "finite numbers" error is because `L.Map` expects the `center` coordinates to be in the range -90 to 90 and -180 to 180 degrees.

In your jsfiddle, you also have the problem that you are selecting `zoom:11`, but only have 7 zoom levels available in your CRS definition.

The Leaflet API always uses WGS84 latitude/longitude coordinates in degrees, so using Proj4leaflet this way won't do what you want. See this [explanation from the Proj4Leaflet project](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/issues/49).

However, EPSG:3857 is already the default CRS in Leaflet, and you can use its built-in methods to convert between meters and WGS84 degrees, without needing either Proj4Leaflet or Proj4js.  See the [Leaflet CRS documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#crs).

```
const proj = L.CRS.EPSG3857;

// Degrees to metres
proj.project(new L.LatLng(51,-2));             // {x: -222638.98158654, y: 6621293.722740}

// Metres to degrees
proj.unproject(new L.Point(-222600, 6621000)); // {lat: 50.998339473, lng: -1.99964982245}
```

It's probably easiest to `unproject` your metre coordinates to WGS whenever you need to pass them to Leaflet, but alternatively you could write overridden versions of some of Leaflet's functions.  These would take metre coordinates, convert them to degrees, then pass them on the original function.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Please correct me if I'm wong (I am very new in the GIS world): The EPSG 3857 coordinate system uses the unit metres, and WGS84 is the long/lat system which uses the unit degree. In my database I have coordinates saved in metres, and to my understanding Leaflet only accepts WGS84 as input (and then internally converts that to 3857). What I am trying to achieve here is to be able to send coordinates to Leaflet using the metre unit. Thanks for pointing out the zoom issue!

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how to convert from metres to WGS84 lat/lon, so that you can use your coordinates in Leaflet without needing Proj4Leaflet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've been stuck here for a couple of days! I'll proceed extending some of Leaflets methods.