# Leaflet : TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers

Tags: leaflet, proj4js

I'm trying to use Leaflet with a specific projection EPSG:2169 (Luref, or Luxembourg).
I saw that if I don't use a "standard" projection like WGS84, I have to use Proj4Leaflet and reference it to the map.

That's what I did for now :

```
this.crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2169',
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49.83333333333334 +lon_0=6.166666666666667 +k=1 +x_0=80000 +y_0=100000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-189.681,18.3463,-42.7695,-0.33746,-3.09264,2.53861,0.4598 +units=m +no_defs');

this.map = L.map('map', {
  center: [ 74000, 96000 ],
  zoom: 3,
  crs: this.crs,
});
```

When I load the page with the map, the console gives me these errors :

```
Cannot read property '3' of undefined
Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

After some Googling, I found that I have to define "resolutions" option. I don't know exactly how it is used, but I took from a sample and here is now how looks the CRS :

```
this.crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2169',
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49.83333333333334 +lon_0=6.166666666666667 +k=1 +x_0=80000 +y_0=100000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-189.681,18.3463,-42.7695,-0.33746,-3.09264,2.53861,0.4598 +units=m +no_defs',
{
  resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128]
});
```

Now when the map is loaded, I have this error in console :

```
TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers
```

And now I don't know what to do next.
Anyone here already had this kind of issue ?

I take a look at this recommended post : [trying to use EPSG:3857 in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462280/trying-to-use-epsg3857-in-leaflet)
But I didn't found what I want. My goal is to have a map prepared in EPSG:2169 so I can retrieve GeoJson data from GeoServer WMS that are in this projection.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to use EPSG:3857 in Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462280/trying-to-use-epsg3857-in-leaflet)

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/348356/115

Comment: This is an instance of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). JCB wants to load data apparently from EPSG:2169, so instead of converting the coordinates to EPSG:4326 via proj4js or the like, JCB decided to do everything in EPSG:2169... and failed. Also note that WMS returns raster and not vector data, and that compliant geojson uses EPSG:4326 exclusively [as per the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-4)

Comment: I didn't know that GeoJSON should return exclusively data in EPSG:4326. That's and interesting point that I'll keep in mind. The source of my problem is that I come from a project in OpenLayers where all data are projected in EPSG:2169, and I'm trying to do the same with Leaflet to compare both tools. That's why I try to do the same, and that's why I ask my question here. If I have to convert incoming EPSG:2169 data in EPSG:4326, I'll look for that, or will stay with OpenLayers.

Answer (score 3):

Proj4Leaflet changes the *display* CRS of the Leaflet map, and not the CRS of `L.LatLng`s. This is in the same way that Leaflet uses EPSG:3857 for display, but the user never sees EPSG:3857 coordinates, and the specified map center (*et al*) is given in EPSG:4326 coordinates.

Initialize your map using the corresponding EPSG:4326 coordinates, in your case:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2169',
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49.83333333333334 +lon_0=6.166666666666667 +k=1 +x_0=80000 +y_0=100000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-189.681,18.3463,-42.7695,-0.33746,-3.09264,2.53861,0.4598 +units=m +no_defs',
{
  resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128]
});

var map = L.map('leaflet', {
  center: [ 49.60, 6.39 ],
  zoom: 3,
  crs: crs,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @IvanSanchez, but it doesn't give the expected result. As you say, I could set any CRS to the map, I have to use EPSG:4326 coordinates to center the view, right ? I also tried with the EPSG:3857 as you mentioned, but in both case I get a grey map with a lot of 404 error in console that OSM tiles cannot be found. I have seen the post about EPSG:3857 before posting my question, and even being a similar issue, I didn't found the answer I was looking for.